# Ask for HTTP authentication only when user is trying to authenticate

Tags: php, http-headers

What I think of is detecting authentication attempt and logging user in using PHP and standart HTTP credentials without bugging him with popup, when he does not try to login. That may sound easy, but we must keep in mind, that browsers check whether site is requesting authentication, and when it does not, they are bugging user with warning and they also send no data.
Is there any bypass? Any trick?

**QUESTION SUMMARY:**

- I want url http://example.com/site to work wihout any promts and popups. User will see the site as *anonymous*.
- I want url http://user:password@example.com/site to work without any popups too. User will see the site as *user*

Comment: Would it be possible to reconfigure your web server (Apache/IIS...) not to require authentication? The you can switch your pages to just use forms-based authentication (user name / password field) where required.

Comment: I already have that form of authentication. My goal was to give user possibility to have nice login link in his bookmarks (please lets avoid talking about security).
And doing this, I wanted to avoid GET parameters.
Turning of Apache HTTP login has no offect since I am using PHP to read authentication headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question: no there is no way around it. The browser will not send the authentication information if it has not been requested by the website, and as you have discovered, it will also show an annoying security warning to the user. You should bite the bullet and use a GET param.